# why li element move on hover of button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a  simple demo `li` elements  Which is **horizontal center** followed by `Play` or `Pause` button (see attached image ).I am able to make this using `Flexbox properties`. but facing few issue

**Issue**:

1. My `li` elements are moving or changing it position when I hover the Button.

**conditions**

1. we can't give hardcoded width to `TEXT` or hover text or PLAY or PAUSE .Text can be as big as possible ?

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/kobezulipe/edit?html,css,output

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
}

.abc{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.list{
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.list li{
   width: 52px;
  margin: 0 9px;
   
}
.list li button{
   border: 1px solid #3A3631;
    width: 52px;
}


.p{
  position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: initial;
    left: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}





.container {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #202020;
  transition: 100ms all ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  padding: 0
}

.button.paused {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #404040;
}

.container:hover span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <ul class='list'>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="p">
    <div class="container">
    <button class='button'>
    </button>
    <span class="text">Play</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Attached expected output

Answer pic
[image]

Comment: updated code link https://jsbin.com/kobezulipe/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's moving because the flexbox in `.abc` `justify-content: center`. When the width of the button changes, everything moves to stay centered.

If you change that to `start` it will not move.

Alternatively, if you don't want the content to move *and* you want to keep it centered, *and* you can't use a hard-coded width, you can try using an overlay. It won't move when you hover, though it might cover up anything next to it:

1. add a second button next to the first one. remove the text from the original.
2. set this button to `position: absolute` so it's positioned above the layout. the parent is already `position: relative`
3. only display the overlay during .p:hover. Hide the original button with `visibility: hidden` so it keeps its width and height.

Example:

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
}

.abc{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.list{
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.list li{
   width: 52px;
  margin: 0 9px;
   
}
.list li button{
   border: 1px solid #3A3631;
    width: 52px;
}

.p{
  position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: initial;
    left: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container, .overlay {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.p:hover .overlay {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.p:hover .container {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #202020;
  transition: 100ms all ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  padding: 0
    overflow: visible;
}

.button.paused {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #404040;
}

.container:hover span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="abc">
  <ul class='list'>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="p">
    <div class="container">
      <button class='button'>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <button class='button'>
      </button>
      <span class="text">Play, this can be very long</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for answering .. it is working only issue is when `text` grow `play` or `pause` . it should come in single line. see update question

Comment: see upated question

Comment: just add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.text` to keep it from wrapping.

Comment: can you update your answer I will check

Comment: ok, it's updated.

Answer (score 1):

new answer: ↓

i rewrote the html. and the `.p` is positioned relative to the `.list`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  btn.classList.toggle("paused");
  document.querySelector(".button");
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.abc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.list {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.list li {
  width: 52px;
  margin: 0 9px;
}
.list li button {
  border: 1px solid #3a3631;
  width: 52px;
}

.p {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: initial;
  /* left: 18px; */
  margin-bottom: 0;

  position: absolute;
  right: -18px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.container {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #202020;
  transition: 100ms all ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.button.paused {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #404040;
}

.container:hover span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <button><span></span></button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button><span></span></button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button><span></span></button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button><span></span></button>
    </li>
    <div class="p">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="button"></button>
        <span class="text">Play longer longer longer</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

hope it can help you。

<strike>you can change the `.p {width: initial;}` to `.p {width: 52px;}`</strike>

Comment: wrong .. not working please remove this

Comment: why wrong? it works fine for me.

Comment: @user5711656 Setting a fixed width solves this. This solution makes your `<li>` not jump on `:hover`

Comment: if possible share jsbin link please

Comment: @user5711656 is this what you are looking for? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lf8oM4h0GUtTynvjBC_4d41HNsz9bfFm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user5711656 I don't use jsbin, but here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/xhm8ycp5/6/) I made the same change in your existing jsbin and it worked as it should.

Comment: thanks for sharing .. see my update .. when text grow it comes in `multi-lines`. it should be in single line

Comment: `li` is not jumbing which is great .. last point is text can be grow as much as possible. but it should be in single line

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

With @kid-jokers answer you can add `white-space: nowrap;` to container div to allow words to span on one line.

```js
 var btn = document.querySelector(".button");

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  btn.classList.toggle('paused');
  document.querySelector(".button");
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
}

.abc{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.list{
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.list li{
   width: 52px;
  margin: 0 9px;
   
}
.list li button{
   border: 1px solid #3A3631;
    width: 52px;
}


.p{
  position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 52px;
    left: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}





.container {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #202020;
  transition: 100ms all ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  padding: 0
}

.button.paused {
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 0px 0 0px 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #404040;
}

.container:hover span {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <ul class='list'>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
    <li><button><span></span></button></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="p">
    <div class="container">
    <button class='button'>
    </button>
    <span class="text">Play WHAM! - Jitterbug</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```